# JPA changing from primary key to composite primary key error class must use consistent access type

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

New to all this so please let me know if anything is missing or incorrect.
Initially I created this class which was using just the primary key of the table like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="serviceRequestActivities"
,catalog="Maven_new"
, uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="serviceReqNr") 
)

public class ServiceRequestActivities  implements java.io.Serializable,DbEntity {

private int activityNr;
private ServiceRequest serviceRequest;
...

@Id 
@Column(name="activityNr", unique=true, nullable=false)
public int getActivityNr() {
    return this.activityNr;
}

public void setActivityNr(int activityNr) {
    this.activityNr = activityNr;
}

@Override
@Transient
public Object getId(){
    return getActivityNr();
}

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="serviceReqNr", nullable=false)
public ServiceRequest getServiceRequest() {
    return this.serviceRequest;
}

public void setServiceRequest(ServiceRequest serviceRequest) {
    this.serviceRequest = serviceRequest;
}

... the other setters and getters

}
```

Then were some changes in the requirements and I have to use a composite primary key to get the object to be updated. I changed it and it looks like this now:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(MyKey.class)
@Table(name="serviceRequestActivities"
,catalog="Maven_new"
, uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="serviceReqNr") 
)

public class ServiceRequestActivities  implements java.io.Serializable,DbEntity {

@Id private int activityNr;
@Id private ServiceRequest serviceRequest;
...

public class MyKey implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Column(name="activityNr", nullable=false)
    private int activityNr;
    private ServiceRequest serviceRequest;

    public int getActivityNr() {
        return this.activityNr;
    }

    public void setActivityNr(int activityNr) {
        this.activityNr = activityNr;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof ServiceRequestActivities)) return false;
        ServiceRequestActivities activity = (ServiceRequestActivities) o;
        return getId() != null && Objects.equals(getId(), activity.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="serviceReqNr", nullable=false)
    public ServiceRequest getServiceRequest() {
        return this.serviceRequest;
    }

    public void setServiceRequest(ServiceRequest serviceRequest) {
        this.serviceRequest = serviceRequest;
    }
}
@Override
@Transient
public Object getId(){

    return getActivityNr();

}
...
the other setters and getters

}
```

not yet able to do completely achieve the change as there is an error complaining that 
"The class must use a consistent access type(either field or property)
There is no ID defined for this entity hierarchy"
Not sure what Is incorrect or what is missing.

Comment: i found a solution even though is not the one I was looking for with this question. I created a new auto increment primary key in the table(activityKey) which will hold a unique combination of the other 2 fields which were initially the compounded key(activityNr and serviceRequestNr). This way my object can be updated properly. I still hope that someone has a solution for my question.